# Pulling Blogspot Posts with PHP

Tags: php, blogspot

I am developing a lightweight app that has a rudimentary news feed, that will be populated from Blogspot. Does anyone know any blogspot php frameworks that can pull the list of items posted within blogspot, and also pull the content (and other data) of an individual post.

Comment: Do the blogs have a feed of some sort, i.e., RSS?

Comment: @JohnCartwright im not sure, i havn't had that much experience with blogspot. In the past, I have done exactly that with twitter, but 140 characters is not enough for a news post in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best/simplest method is to simply use [Blogger's RSS feed](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97933). There are too many [RSS parsers/readers in PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+rss+feed+reader) to shake a stick at.

If you really want to employ the Blogger API and fetch the posts, there are some Zend libraries that are maintained by Blogger that you can utilize.

Here is the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#GettingStarted) explaining how to install the Zend libs and here is an [example that fetches all posts](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#RetrievingWithoutQuery).

I've used this personally (for some more advanced manipulations) and it works like a charm.

But trust me on the RSS feeds. : )

Comment: I'd also use RSS. I was asked to pull a blog into my website, and after displaying it, backup any new posts. I used the RSS feed provided by blogger, and SimpleXML in PHP. I think this is the easiest solution. Use this feed: http://yourblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss